# jquery selector and events propagation

Tags: jquery, events, selector, propagation

It is a question with partial answers :

I first have developed a classical Jquery development with many flat selectors, but I needed to develop a "A tag" handler `$("a").click (function.... )` to hold more complex cases.

The handler begins with a filter which returns true so that the events propagation will go on normally.

This functions well for all standard A tags, but do not function for A tag which action is defined by a jquery selector using the name of the element :

```
$('#elementname').on('click' .... )
```

I have performed various test without success, event propogation doesn't reach the Jquery selectors.

The alone solution which naturally functions (but not fair) is to filter by a class all the other a elements and define a second level filter which contains the previously existing selectors : it is to do everything manually. It is not a good solution.

How can I keep the Jquery structure for all named A tags and hold particular cases with a defined handler using normal event propagation rules.

Thanks
best regards
Trebly

Comment: Can you set an example for us?

Comment: Can you show us what you have trying?

Answer (score 0):

I explain in another way. I imagine that my explanations where not clear at all.
So I don't give a full example but a simplified syntax which the architecture is :

```
// html 
<a id="elementId1" .... ></a>
<a id="elementId2" .... ></a>
<a id="elementId3" .... ></a>
<a id="elementId4" .... ></a>

// JQuery
$('#elementId1').on('click', f1() )
$('#elementId2').on('click', f2() )
$('#elementId3').on('click', f3() )
$('#elementId4').on('click', f4() )

$("a").on('click', function() {
     var $id = $(this).get(0).hash;
     if ( $id.indexOf("element") >= 0 ) return true;
     if  ( $id.indexOf("someothers") >= 0 ) {
          do something special
     }
     // remaining cases
     return true; // end bubbling then goto standard system events management
});
```

With this any `<a id="any" href ="<an url>" >Got to this</a>`

will be fired with his options.

Without the `$("a").on...` the  `$('#elementId1').on('click' .... )` are handled.
But these JQ handlers are no more catch when `$("a").on(click....` is set.
The events set by JQ for these id are no more handled (the click event associated by system to A tag is forgotten-hidden by the event set by JQ).

**My question :**

Is it a way so that such JQ `<selector>.on('click'...`  should be handled as others system events. 
The A tag handler is then a hook to perform particular actions on some identifiable elements click event without managing everything which is not standard.

Is it a true or wrong problem ?

Best regards

Trebly

---

Note : the solution, which use the $("a") JQ object and holds into the whole hierarchy, naturally functions :

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
     var $id = $(this).get(0).hash;
     if ( $id.indexOf("element") >= 0 ) {
         if ($id.indexOf("element1") >= 0 ) { f1() }
         else if  ($id.indexOf("element2") >= 0 ) { f2() }
         else if  ($id.indexOf("element3") >= 0 ) { f3() }
         else if  ($id.indexOf("element4") >= 0 ) { f3() }
     }
     if  ( $id.indexOf("someothers") >= 0 ) {
          do something special
     }
     // remaining cases
     return true; // end bubbling then goto standard system events management
});
```

This way seems simple, but only in simple cases. When there are interactions it can become difficult to hold.